# Normal distribution problem with unknown mean and standard deviation

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose the weights W (kg) of a male population is normally distributed. If we know P(W≤70)=0.65, and P(W≤50)=0.35. Now from this population, 15 males are randomly selected, what is the probability that at least 3 of them weigh more than 65kg?

Answer (score 0):

So here is how you solve it

Clearly, the mean of the Gaussian is 60kg. (Draw a diagram you will see it, as 50 and 70 are points at equal distances (P(>=70) == P(<=50))

Let P be the probability that is asked

since the events of getting any people above 65 kg is mutually exclusive

P = 1 - P(getting 0 above 65kg) - P(getting 1 above 65 kg) - P(getting 2 above 65 kg)

Let p and q be P(<=65) and P(>65)

You can calculate p and q easily (just compare with standard normal gaussian)

But you know what to do

calculate

P(0) = (p)^15

P(1) = (p)^14*(q)*(15C1) = 15*(0.5)^15

P(2) = (p)^13*(q)^2*(15C2) = (15C2)(0.5)^15

EDIT : Sorry for the arithmetic mistake earlier

Comment: Thank you so much. Ii always thought it was a binomial probability problem.

Comment: We have $P(W \leq 50) = 0.35$ and $P(W \geq 70) = 0.35$, so the distribution is symmetric around the midpoint between $50$ and $70$, which is $60$, not $65$.

Comment: @Bungo can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @PrajaktaAmbegaokar The mean of the Gaussian is 60kg, not 65kg. Unfortunately this means that the nice 0.5 probabilities will need to be modified.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you. I will try working on it.